# PowerBI countries map where the first column is highlighted

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I need a map with the countries where I can see which car is on each country.
My data is like this:
[image]

I would like to see an interactive map where I can see what cars I have on the country.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Split your Countries column by ',' delimiter - then Unpivot Other Columns on the Car column. You will end up with a tall table where you can use car (attribute) and country (value) on a map.

You will need a Lookup table to convert the short country values into proper country names i.e. US needs a mapping to 'United States'